# What directory to extract Entity Framework 6 NuGet package to

Tags: nuget, entity-framework-6

I'm working in VS 2012. I just downloaded the Entity Framework 6 Alpha3 NuGet package.

I put it in the NuGet folder for quick access.

When I use the command

```
PM> Get-Package -Filter EntityFramework -ListAvailable
```

(and related filters 'EF6' and 'Entity')
I cannot find my download.

I can find

Glimpse.EF6. This is not what I'm looking for.

My path to the download:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Visual Studio 2012\EF6 Alpha3
```

My question is *where do I need to put the download file so that I can locate it when adding the solution to my project.*

I understand how I will add the package to every solution I wish to use it in. I have read the MSDN and codeplex documentation.
I understand that I am merely looking for the package to add to my solution. This is my problem. I put it in the NuGet Program folder and am still unable to find this.

I am *sure* I'm missing something simple. I am just asking where to put the download of the Alpha3 version of EF6 so that I can locate it using the -ListAvailable command.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you download the package?

Comment: Nuget usage is very simple. Just read the minimal documentation.

Comment: @GertArnold, I just downloaded it from the CodePlex for NuGet packages at [this link](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/releases) .

Comment: OK, do in Visual Studio using the Library Package Manager while you're in a solution.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold-I really just want to know if a local NuGet package libraries folder exists in the first place so I can keep things organized. (If I am to continuously reference these libraries, I would imagine there is a place VS looks in by default to find them.)

Comment: I never solved this. I needed to be able to self-install my framework packages directly from the site (not thru VS2012) because my company's firewall does not allow me to connect to Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can read from  your question and comments, it seems like you are missing the basic understanding of how NuGet works and how to use it.

I would highly recommend that you start by reading some documentation about NuGet. The [Getting Started page](https://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started) provides a brief introduction, and pay especially good attention to the section named *Working with NuGet Packages*.

[docs.nuget.org](http://docs.nuget.org/) is an extensive resource to everything you might need to know about NuGet. The first four links should provide you more than enough information:

- [Overview](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/overview)
- [Installing NuGet](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget)
- [Managing NuGet Packages Using The Dialog](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog)
- [Using the Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

To answer your specific question about *where* NuGet packages gets download: the default location is in the *packages* folder at the root of your solution location. You should however not need to think anything about this, but instead read the above links to *understad* the basics of NuGet.

Comment: Thanks @Nailug. I was really just looking for an answer regarding where to leave the install package for the download file, since it will be accessed over and over each time it is referenced within the a new project. I get what's going on with NuGet, I was just surprised there wasn't a library folder for the *download* packages. There's a NuGetFolder I found and I just put it there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @UB3571: either you're *still* not understanding how NuGet works, or you're having problems formulating your real question. When you say *"where to leave the install package"* that is completely against how you should work with NuGet. You *should not* think about this. When you add a NuGet package to your project, NuGet will by itself download the package from the official NuGet feed (or one of your own feeds, if you have one), and place the downloaded package in the *packages* folder inside your solution.

Comment: I understand completely how to use these parts of NuGet/Visual Studio. All I am asking is where to put my new downloads for updated NuGet packages so I can find them using the Package Manager. I understand that the Package Manager is a command line prompt, what the commands are, and that I need to simply list the available packages. If I can't find the thing I just downloaded, I can't install it. It's right in the folder that should be easily accessible to the Package Manager, as it is local to the NuGet Folder.

Comment: @UB3571: When you say *"All I am asking is where to put my new downloads for updated NuGet packages so I can find them using the Package Manager."*, you're *still* looking at it the wrong way. If you for instance want to install the latest pre-release version of EntityFramework, you'd have to write the following in the Package Manager Console: `Install-Package EntityFramework -Prerelease`. NuGet will then do ***two*** things: (A) *automatically **download*** the package for you, and (B) *install* it in your project.